# F#: explicit type parameters in operator binding

Tags: generics, f#, operators, explicit, type-parameter

I'm trying to define operator with the explicit type parameters and constraints:

```
let inline (===)<'a, 'b
    when 'a : not struct
     and 'b : not struct> a b = obj.ReferenceEquals (a,b)
```

It works well in F# 2.0, but produces the:

> ***warning FS1189:***
>  Type parameters must be placed directly
>   adjacent to the type name, e.g. "type
>   C<'T>", not     type "C   <'T>"

So what is the right way to do explicit type arguments specification for operator definition?

p.s. Please don't tell me about implicit type parameters and some other workarounds, I want to solve concretely this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A bug in the compiler means that symbolic operators are never considered directly adjacent to type parameters.  You can workaround via e.g.

```
let inline myeq<'a, 'b 
    when 'a : not struct 
    and 'b : not struct> a b = obj.ReferenceEquals (a,b) 

let inline (===) a b = myeq a b
```

Comment: Also active patterns have the same bug:
`let (|SomePatternName|)<'a, 'b> x = x`

Answer (score 4):

```
let inline (===) (a : 'TA when 'TA : not struct) (b : 'TB when 'TB : not struct) = 
    obj.ReferenceEquals (a,b)
```